# Custom css using css applies only at homepage not the entire website

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I tried to apply @font-face a custom font to the whole pages of the website
but it does apply only on the homepage elements not the entire pages.

I tried mentioned below:

```html
*{
font-family: 'fontname';

}
```

Comment: If you have multiple HTML pages, then you need to load the particular CSS in all of them.

Comment: is your custom font available in all pages?

Comment: If you have a base template and you are including other template inside it, then add it in your base template or if you are adding html to pages separately and include your css in each of them. Do check the class name in every page as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to put that css and the right link of font to all of your pages

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to give the body, or a parent container of the homepage a specific class or ID, and then apply the font to that selector - something like:

```
<body class=“homepage">...
```

And then the css:

```
body.homepage {
  font-family: 'my-font';
 }
```